# how to link two websites together on a 3rd party server

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, relative-path

I have two websites I have created and they need to be uploaded to a 3rd party client server.  I have one part of each website pointing to the other (for various reasons as each website if for a different dept). I do not know the exact destination server location, so I do not know the exact URL destination/server folder destination.  If I upload a ZIP file containing both websites, is there a HTML format I can use for the links on each website to ensure each website (as they will be located in the same folder on the client server) links across to the other?

Comment: You may consider tagging database and/or server as well.

I currently host two sites on my host domain, one is on a sub folder but directs to its proper domain. I do not however link them though I would think that would be as simple as constructing the proper logic in the back end to do so, in the terms of what you need. Perhaps adding a bit more about the relationship of the two websites in terms of your back end code might help as well. I assume you wish to take a file from one server and place in the Db of another server, yet you are not sure what the destination location is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

There are 3 types of urls: Absolute, Relative, and Root-relative URLs

Absolute look like this: http://www.example.com/folder1/index.html

Relative looks like this: index.html (Assuming you are already on a page in the same folder such as http://www.example.com/folder1/page2.html)

And root-relative urls: /folder1/index.html

You want the last one.